# ‏GenericArguments[0], 'EntityGenericBase`1[TModel]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TModel'

Tags: c#, winforms

Can someone help me in resolving this issue:
I created a Generic Base "User Control" using c# Winforms as fellow:

```
public class EntityGenericBase<TModel> : UserControl
    where TModel : class, IEntityClass, new()
{}
```

and i have created another User Control that inherits "EntityGenericBase" above as fellow:

```
public class DepartmentView : EntityGenericBase<Department>
{
    public DepartmentView():base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

But unluckily when i try to view the user control in design mode, i receive the following error:

GenericArguments[0], 'Department', on 'EntityGenericBase`1[TModel]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TModel’.

## I can still run the application without any problem.

Remark: When i remove the constraint "where clause", everything works fine.

## I use "Visual Studio Community 2017"

Comment: The error message saying `Department` is not implementing `IEntityClass` or It's not a class, or it doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your valued response. Yes it works fine but without the ‘where’ constraint.

Comment: You're welcome. Read the comment/answer below carefully and make sure all the criteria has been satisfied with `Department` class.

Comment: But it produce the said error when I add ‘where TModel : class, IEntityClass, new(). The problem is resolved when I remove ‘IEntityClass’ from the constraint

Comment: So Implement IEntityClass for Department class.

Comment: I tried this also with no success.

Comment: Actually, seems to be a known issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931853/vs-designer-error-genericarguments0-x-on-y-violates-the-constraint-of-ty

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says

> GenericArguments[0], 'Department', on 'EntityGenericBase`1[TModel]'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'TModel’.

Your model Department violates one or many of the constraints

```
class, IEntityClass, new()
```

Department is not one or many of these

1. It is not a class
2. It does not implement the IEntityClass interface
3. It does not have a parameterless constructor

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check further although I have checked several times.

Comment: I have Checked and everything looks fine, kindly take a look at 'Department' Class and 'IEntityClass'

Comment: //IEntityClass interface

    public interface IEntityClass
    {
        string ModelName { get; set; }
    }
  
    //EntityClass Class

        public abstract class EntityClass : IEntityClass
    {
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
    }
 
    //Deparment Class

    public class Department : EntityClass
    {
        private static Department _default;
        public static Department Default { get { return _default ?? (_default = new Department()); } }

        public Department()
        {
        }
    }

Comment: @نديمالجود ok, why don't you just get rid of the IEntityClass interface and use the abstract EntityClass in the constraint instead? Looks like you don't need the interface when you have the abstract class

Comment: One thing worth mentioning. Once I restart visual studio, I can display the ‘UserControl’ in design mode but as soon as I build the project the error occurs

Comment: @نديمالجود, did you ever find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same behavior...

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue for which the only resolution appears to be a restart
[VS Designer error: GenericArguments[0], 'X' on 'Y' violates the constraint of type parameter 'Z'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931853/vs-designer-error-genericarguments0-x-on-y-violates-the-constraint-of-ty)